# Как использовать счетчик времени для подсчета очков в Python?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, tkinter, таймер

Пишу небольшую игру в Python 3.7. Понадобилось использовать время для подсчета очков. Т.е. каждую секунду с момента запуска программы к счету должно прибавляться одно очко. Имеется данный код, который нужно доработать до рабочего состояния или предложить альтернативные способы решения проблемы

```
score = 0

def label2():
    global SCORElabel
    SCORElabel = c.create_text(350, 10, width=300, text="Score: " + str(score), fill='#fff', anchor=NW)

def scoremeter():
    global score
    game_time = time.clock()
    if game_time//1==0:
        score+=1
        c.delete(SCORElabel)
        label2()
        scoremeter()
    else:
        scoremeter()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в `tkinter` есть встроенная функция `tkinter.Tk.after("second", func)` которая позволяет повторять функцию раз в определенное кол-во секунд пример ниже

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    score = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Количество очков 0")
        self.label.pack()
        self.score_plus()

    def score_plus(self):
        self.score += 5
        self.label["text"] = "Количество очков {}".format(self.score)
        self.after(1000, self.score_plus)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```